# Downloading files from an http server in python

Tags: python, automation

Using urllib2, we can get the http response from a web server.  If that server simply holds a list of files, we could parse through the files and download each individually.  However, I'm not sure what the easiest, most pythonic way to parse through the files would be.

When you get a whole http response of the generic file server list, through urllib2's urlopen() method, how can we neatly download each file?

Comment: Would you care to give us three or four lines of sample source from this 'list of files', so we can see what sort of extra formatting might be involved?

Answer (score 12):

Urllib2 might be OK to retrieve the list of files. For downloading large amounts of binary files PycURL http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/ is a better choice. This works for my IIS based file server:

```
import re
import urllib2
import pycurl

url = "http://server.domain/"
path = "path/"
pattern = '<A HREF="/%s.*?">(.*?)</A>' % path

response = urllib2.urlopen(url+path).read()

for filename in re.findall(pattern, response):
    with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
        curl = pycurl.Curl()
        curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url+path+filename)
        curl.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, fp)
        curl.perform()
        curl.close()
```

Comment: I didn't do speed tests, but it is also possible to use `BeautifulSoup` to get all `<a>`s and then `.text` from them.

Answer (score 9):

You can use urllib.urlretrieve (in Python 3.x: urllib.request.urlretrieve):

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('http://site.com/', filename='filez.txt')
```

This should be work :)

and this is a fnction that can do the same thing (using urllib):

```
def download(url):
    webFile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    localFile = open(url.split('/')[-1], 'w')
    localFile.write(webFile.read())
    webFile.close()
    localFile.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you guarantee that the URL you're requesting is a directory listing? If so, can you guarantee the format of the directory listing?

If so, you could use [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) to parse the returned document and find all of the elements that hold the path to a file, then iterate over those elements and download each file.

Comment: And some yet like to use pyquery ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the index file

   If it's really huge, it may be worth reading a chunk at a time;
   otherwise it's probably easier to just grab the whole thing into memory.
2. Extract the list of files to get

   If the list is xml or html, use a proper parser;
   else if there is much string processing to do, use regex;
   else use simple string methods.

   Again, you can parse it all-at-once or incrementally.
   Incrementally is somewhat more efficient and elegant,
   but unless you are processing multiple tens of thousands
   of lines it's probably not critical.
3. For each file, download it and save it to a file.

   If you want to try to speed things up, you could try
   running multiple download threads;

   another (significantly faster) approach might be
   to delegate the work to a dedicated downloader
   program like Aria2 http://aria2.sourceforge.net/ -
   note that Aria2 can be run as a service and controlled
   via XMLRPC, see http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/aria2/wiki/XmlrpcInterface#InteractWitharia2UsingPython

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (which is an HTML/XML parser) to parse the page for a list of files. Then, pycURL would definitely come in handy.

Another method, after you've got the list of files, is to use [urllib.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) in a way similar to wget in order to simply download the file to a location on your filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-convential way, but although it works

```
fPointer = open(picName, 'wb')
self.curl.setopt(self.curl.WRITEFUNCTION, fPointer.write) 


urllib.urlretrieve(link, picName) - correct way
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an untested solution:

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://server.com/file.txt')
urls = response.read().replace('\r', '').split('\n')

for file in urls:
  print 'Downloading ' + file

  response = urllib2.urlopen(file)

  handle = open(file, 'w')
  handle.write(response.read())
  handle.close()
```

It's untested, and it probably won't work. This is assuming you have an actual *list* of files inside of another file. Good luck!