# Importing multiple CSV from webpage

Tags: loops, csv, dataframe, import

I was trying to import two CSV files from the following page.

Webpage
http://www.football-data.co.uk/data.php

CSV links:
http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/I1.csv

http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/I2.csv

I tried the following loop:

```
url = r'http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617' 

    allFiles = glob.glob(url + "/*.csv")
    frame = pd.DataFrame()
    list_ = []
    for file_ in allFiles:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_ )
        list_.append(df)
    frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

But I get the following error

```
    raise ValueError('No objects to concatenate')

ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

Not sure why!

Answer (score 0):

Its because `glob` doesn't work on URLs, as you expect it to work like a directory.

`allFiles` is set to `[]`.
 You need to manually create the list `allFiles` with the 2 URLs.

Comment: Well, I would like eventually to be able to loop through all the csv of the webpage, any other approach that does not require entering the list manually?

Comment: One solution is downloading all csv files, and save in a folder. Then iterate using `glob`

Comment: Or just get a list of all URLs. See this [amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34718858/8278951)